# Error inflating class fragment. What can I do here?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I was coding this program the other day, hoping that the fragment was doing okay, but it isn't. My project is a **Relative Layout** app where the GPS map will show up on the screen first thing the activity pops up, and then the choices to view some of the Javanese culture of Indonesia (in the form of **Grid - Card View** combination), will be available for selection.

Here, in this line, I have a class fragment inflation error, according to Logcat :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_island); // Erroring line

    KerisCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.KerisCard);
    TradClothesCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.TradClothesCard);
    TradHouseCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.TradHouseCard);
    TariMerakCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.TariMerakCard);



    SupportMapFragment javaMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.java_island_map);
    javaMapFragment.getMapAsync(this); . . . }
```

In retrospect, I'm not very familiar to the concept of fragments as the classes I've been attending aren't going too detailed on the usage of fragments. Also, I have to note without the declaring the object references ((CardView) declarations on the onCreate() function), this error would not show up, and the app will be executable as normal.

Comment: your fragment layout has problem .fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making support fragment reference create fragment reference directly and call method from fragment.
SampleFragment fragment=new SampleFragment()
Fragment .someMethod
Here is a confusion 
Do you want to open fragment in activity ?
Because you are trying to find fragment from id ,so have you created  in xml if not then there is problem.